# What kind of output from ./configure is considered bad?

Tags: compilation, configure, autoconf, automake

I'm compiling several libraries that use automake. When I run the `./configure` command (with a few flags thrown in), most of the checks pass with a 'yes' but several of them have a 'no'. Is this necessarily leading to my compilation error?

In other words, do I have to have all 'yes' for it to *properly* (i.e. not just by complete luck) compile?

Comment: Well that depends on those tests. But commonly there are **many** tests coming back with a *no* without causing any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this necessarily leading to my compilation error?

It's not supposed to, but might in reality.  One of the jobs of `configure` scripts is to try and work around missing/broken functionality in the build environment.  Sometimes some of the tests that are run in `configure` might not even be directly relevant to your build.  In a perfect world, the code being configured *should* be written to work if either a `yes` or a `no` is returned for any test (or fail the build, if it somehow doesn't have a work around).

> In other words, do I have to have all 'yes' for it to properly (i.e. not just by complete luck) compile?

No.